# Ignite : system.out.print commands in code not logging into the log file

Tags: apache-spark, ignite, apache-spark-2.0

I started two ignite server nodes with the following on console /root/apache-ignite-fabric-2.3.0-bin/bin/ignite.sh -v

From a remote client, I run the ClusterGroup example program. I see the below type of logs (printed from system.out.print) in both the server nodes on the console.

```
>>> Hello Node: 34579566-5a66-4ff7-af39-36fe76c1af5e
>>> Hello Node: 34579566-5a66-4ff7-af39-36fe76c1af5e
>>> Hello Node: 34579566-5a66-4ff7-af39-36fe76c1af5e
```

However, when I move the service into systemd in the server nodes, I DONT get the above prints in log file in work/logs/ folder. Below is my systemd file. why would system.print logs not come in filelogger but work perfectly on console? How do I fix it?

```
[Unit]
Description=ignite dbl
After=network.target
Wants=network.target

[Service]

type=forking
ExecStart=/root/apache-ignite-fabric-2.3.0-bin/bin/ignite.sh -v
KillMode=control-group

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I am using ignite 2.3.0 release. did not change any other config files.

Comment: this could be likely bug in filelogger of ignite. I see the missing messages from java/system.out.prints in syslog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.out` is not redirected to the logger. Change the code to use `IgniteLogger` instead if you want these print outs to appear in log file.

Comment: OK. I was just running Ignite examples provided.